# No resource identifier found for attribute ' Camerazoom and Cameratilt ' in package with Eclipse Juno ADT bundle

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, eclipse-juno

Dear fellow programmers.
I am searching the internet for hours now for a solution but I can not seem to find it.
I get two errors:

- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cameraZoom' in 
   package 'com.avans.airports'

  - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cameraTilt' in 
    package 'com.avans.airports'

Also in combination with these errors. My R.java file is missing from eclipse.

I DID add the google play services library. I tried everything but can not find a solution and I am stuck for hours now.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/the_map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
map:cameraTilt="45"
map:cameraZoom="14"
/>
```

And in this piece of code:

```
private Airport airport;
private TextView txtName;
private TextView txtLatitude;
private TextView txtLongitude;
private TextView txtElavation;
private TextView txtIso;
private TextView txtMunicipality;
private Button btnMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);

    txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtLatitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLatitude);
    txtLongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLongitude);
    txtElavation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtElavation);
    txtIso = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtIso);
    txtMunicipality = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMunicipality);
    btnMap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMap);
```

I get the error, R cannot resolve to variable

Please help me out

Comment: I am also facing same issue. I have updated my play service version to 10.0.1

Answer (score 0):

try to add this line in your gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
```